# How to understand the matmul function when matrix a is two-dimensional matrix and b is three-dimaimensional matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

```
a=np.arange(8).reshape(2,2,2)
b=np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
print(np.matmul(a,b))
```

the Result is:
[[[ 2  3]
  [ 6 11]]

[[10 19]
  [14 27]]]
How to understand the result? How does it come about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: it "broadcasts" the second 2d matrix to a 3d matrix, and then performs a "mapping" so, it maps the elementwise submatrices to new submatrices in the result.

As the [documentation on `np.matmul` [numpy-doc]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) says:

> **`numpy.matmul(a, b, out=None)`**
>
> Matrix product of two arrays.
>
> The behavior depends on the arguments in the following way.
>
> 1. If both arguments are 2-D they are multiplied like conventional matrices.
> 2. If **either argument is N-D, N > 2**, it is treated as a **stack of matrices residing in the last two indexes** and broadcast
>      accordingly.
> 3. If the first argument is 1-D, it is promoted to a matrix by prepending a 1 to its dimensions. After matrix multiplication the
>      prepended 1 is removed.
> 4. If the second argument is 1-D, it is promoted to a matrix by appending a 1 to its dimensions. After matrix multiplication the
>      appended 1 is removed.

So here the second item is applicable. So first the second matrix is "broadcasted" to the 3d variant as well, so that means that we multiple:

```
array([[[0, 1],
        [2, 3]],

       [[4, 5],
        [6, 7]]])
```

with:

```
array([[[0, 1],
        [2, 3]],

       [[0, 1],
        [2, 3]]])
```

and we see these as *stacked* matrices. So first we multiply:

```
array([[0, 1],      array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])  x        [2, 3]])
```

which gives us:

```
array([[ 2,  3],
       [ 6, 11]])
```

and then the elementwise second submatrices:

```
array([[4, 5],      array([[0, 1],
       [6, 7]])  x        [2, 3]])
```

an this gives us:

```
array([[10, 19],
       [14, 27]])
```

we thus stack these together into the result, and obtain:

```
>>> np.matmul(a, b)
array([[[ 2,  3],
        [ 6, 11]],

       [[10, 19],
        [14, 27]]])
```

Although the behavior is thus perfectly defined, it might be better to use this feature carefully, since there are other "sensical" definitions of what a "matrix product" on 3d matrices with 2d matrices might look like, and these are thus not used here.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the multiplication more explicitly as a summation. So, if `a` has dimensions `(i, j, k)` and `b` has dimensions `(k, l)` then the result will have dimensions of `(i, j, l)`.

[image]

In code this can be written (very explicitly) like so:

```
def matmul(a, b):
  dim1, dim2, dim3 = a.shape
  dim4 = b.shape[1]
  c = np.zeros(shape=(dim1, dim2, dim4))
  for i in range(dim1):
    for j in range(dim2):
      for l in range(dim4):
        c[i, j, l] = sum(a[i, j, k] * b[k, l] for k in range(dim3))
  return c
```

If you tried printing out the result from this `matmul()` function it will be the same as the numpy function.

**Note:** This function is very inefficient and also it works only when a has 3 dimensions and b has two but it can be generalized very easily.